# cant connect using SoapClient PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect and use a WebService with PHP and SoapClient, but getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in /www/1/html/webservices/tuev-nord-ass/soapclientconnect.php:21
```

I have SOAP already installed. But still dont know why i am getting this error. I am new to web services and might be doing mistake somewhere.

WSDL link:

```
http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl
```

My code:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');

$wsdl = 'http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';

$options = array('trace' => true);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, 
array( 
'Benutzer' =>           'desenbeck',
'Kennwort' =>           'desenbeck',
'KonzernID' =>          '100',
'Händler-Nr' =>         'INT31303',
'DMS-ID' =>             'A13T2D19',
'encoding'=>            'ISO-8859-1'
)
);
//Returns list of available SOAP functions described in the WSDL for the Web service. 
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
//some parameters to send
$result = $client->Login('Benutzer', 'Kennwort', 'KonzernID', 'Händler-Nr', 'DMS-ID');
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Theres no method called LoginResponse in the wsdl. Taking a quick look Id recommend you to try just `Login`

Comment: I tried to change it to Login and its giving this error now:  Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string 'H\xe4...' is not a valid utf-8 string in /www/1/html/webservices/tuev-nord-ass/soapclientconnect.php   Its a login request response technique which i am not able to handle properly as i am new to webservice ..

Comment: Try adding a parameter encoding like: `new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));` or with `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: can you please tell me how to add , i tried to do it but its again giving the same error ..Please check the updated question...

Comment: Try putting the encoding together with your param array:array( 
'Benutzer' =>           'deshmukh',
'Kennwort' =>           'deshmukh',
'KonzernID' =>          '100',
'Händler-Nr' =>         'INT31303',
'DMS-ID' =>             'A13T2D19',
'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1' )

Comment: :( i tried to add it please check the updated question and now i am getting error as Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in /www/1/html/webservices/tuev-nord-ass/soapclientconnect.php:21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string indexed array for parameter:

```
$param = array ('user' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
    'corporate_group_id' => 'test',
    'dealer_number' => 'test',
    'dms_id' => 'test',
    'dms_image_url' => 'test',
    'dms_keepalive_url' => 'test',
    'dms_followup_url' => 'test');

//some parameters to send
$result = $client->Login($param);
```